# Detect anomalies on Big Data (19GB of txt files)

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, neural-network, rdd, autoencoder

I want to detect anomalies in [this](https://dataverse.harvard.edu/dataset.xhtml?persistentId=doi:10.7910/DVN/EGZHFV) data (around 19GB of .txt files).

My approach so far is moving the files in my hadoop hdfs, and run pyspark where I have my jupyter notebook. I have my pyspark DataFrame with preprocessed data, but I can't fit the model (in my case, I want to use an autoencoder). What am I doing wrong? Happy to reconsider my approach, but I really want to make autoencoder work or use neural networks to detect anomalies.

I'll provide the full code

```
# Load the data
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("TelecomActivityPreprocessing").getOrCreate()
data = spark.read.text("/user1/dataverse_files/*.txt")

# Preprocess the data
preprocessed_data = (...)

# Prepare the data for training the autoencoder
X_train = preprocessed_data.select("*")  # "*" to take all input features
rdd = X_train.rdd

# Define a function to train the autoencoder model on each partition
def train_autoencoder(partition):

    # Create a new autoencoder model for each partition
    autoencoder = Sequential([
        Dense(encoding_dim, activation='relu', input_shape=(input_dim,)),
        Dense(input_dim, activation='sigmoid')
    ])

    # Compile and fit the autoencoder model on the partition data
    autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
    autoencoder.fit(partition, partition, epochs=10, batch_size=32)

# Train the autoencoder model on each partition of the RDD
rdd.foreachPartition(train_autoencoder)
```

I get this error while fitting:
`y4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe. : org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 17.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 17.0 (TID 289) (10.0.2.15 executor driver): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last)`